# I'm getting error when trying to import reserve from urlresolver

Tags: python, django

when i try to import reverse in my models.py file with the following line: `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` i'm getting this error :`ImportError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers`.I'm learning django from youtube ,and here is the url of the video that i'm watching : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eouZwgKuA5k.How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Django 1.10+, the import has changed to:

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

However, the old import should still work in Django 1.10 and 1.11.

If the old import is giving you an error, that suggests that either your Django install is broken, or you have installed the master branch of Django (which will become 2.0). I would avoid using the master branch.

If possible, use the same Django version that the tutorial was written for, otherwise you might hit more problems like this. If the tutorial was written for Django < 1.8 then I would avoid it, as it is out of date.

Comment: it worked perfectly,the tutorials django version is 1.9.1

Answer (score 3):

This case, you imported `reverse` as follows:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

Upgrade your Django version, use the following command

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

and then try again.